# For a Broker/Dealer, what technology is appropriate to limit transaction to a given state?

Tags: web-application, access-control, legal

[The SEC](http://www.sec.gov/divisions/marketreg/bdguide.htm) allows for individuals to not register with them if they don't permit business with users outside of the state:

> A broker-dealer that conducts all of its business in one state does
>   not have to register with the SEC. (State registration is another
>   matter. See Part III, below.) The exception provided for intrastate
>   broker-dealer activity is very narrow. To qualify, all aspects of all
>   transactions must be done within the borders of one state. This means
>   that, without SEC registration, a broker-dealer cannot participate in
>   any transaction executed on a national securities exchange or Nasdaq.
>   Also, information posted on the Internet that is accessible by persons
>   in another state would be considered an interstate offer of securities
>   or investment services that would require Federal broker-dealer
>   registration.

What technology or implementation is sufficient to protect a website and limit its access to a given state?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, virtually anything you do using phone lines or the Internet constitutes interstate commerce in the United States.  Congress and the Department of Justice have taken this position to ensure they can get their fingers into anything they decide they want to regulate or prosecute.  I really think you need a legal definition, and not a technical definition.

Answer (score 1):

A private network using leased lines or private VPN's may be sufficient enough for this. I guess there would need to be the adequate paper work to show that your end-users are all within the same state that you are doing business and you are doing due diligence to ensure that is correct.

But yeah, a private VPN would ensure random users from other states do not access your services?